# Session Transfer

Tags: http, session, cookies, web-crawler

Have a question on sessions, heres the scenario I am facing,

User hits site scraper.com and makes a request, this triggers web server of scraper.com to initiate a session on "parent.com", the web server makes multiple
POSTs and GETs to parent.com and arrives at a checkout page. Now the web server of scraper.com wants the user's browser to load the checkout page of "parent.com", the same checkout page which **scraper**
reached through the session it initiated. In order to do this the user's browser should hit parent.com with the same session id as the one that **scraper**'s web
server has, this I think can't be done as cross domain cookies are not allowed.

This is very similar to doing a search on kayak.com and when the user selects a flight from Delta Airlines the checkout page of delta.com loads.

How can this be implemented? Is it possible to implement this with the co-operation of parent.com or in above example delta.com?

If **scraper** and parent are having an agreement what exactly should parent support for the **scraper** domain to make requests like above possible?

I hope I did not complicate the description, please let me know. Any responses would be very much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: check this man http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084114/cross-domain-cookies

Comment: @tienrocker thanks, I guess other than involving the parent site there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I've been programming for about 10 months now.  While creating a large scale application to make user's lives easier for a particular travel company that doesn't do multi-hop trip planning I ran into the same problem.  They use ASPX so I've had to successfully determine the _EVENTTARGET that invokes the proper _doPostBack (If you've never messed with ASP, it's annoying like that).  Anyhow, I get everything done, the algorithms written, and the emulated browser to successfully add items to a checkout basket only to realize what I learned early on in my programming career.  Though shalt never assign cookies to a domain though dost not own.  Lol.  What ever happened with this?