# How to delete all cookies for facebook.com?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to delete all cookies created after Facebook login.

using PHP I use `setCookie('CookieName')` method without any value. But It didn't work.

Is there any way to delete all cookie for a website by using PHP/JavaScript?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See the answer here

```
// unset cookies
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#73484

Comment: foreach( array_keys($_COOKIE) as $name ){ .. }

Answer (score 3):

PHP on your server cannot alter cookies that are set by facebook.com - only the cookies set by your domain. Same issue with JavaScript running on your page.

Are the cookies really Facebook's? or one's set by the SDKs on your domain?

Comment: then you can't delete them.

Answer (score 1):

Security policy will not allow you to manage other sites cookies, so there is now way to delete facebook.com cookies from your script.

Correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I don't think its possible to do what you are trying to do. You mess around with (set, alter or delete) cookies from your own domain. So if you are serving stuff from anywhere other than facebook, you will not be able to effect the facebook cookies.

Here is another stackoverflow thread on the same issue [Cross domain cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084114/cross-domain-cookies)

Answer (score 0):

To delete a cookie you *have already set on your own domain* you can use:

```
setCookie('CookieName', '', time()-3600);
```

From [the manual](http://php.net/setcookie):

> When deleting a cookie you should assure that the expiration date is
>   in the past, to trigger the removal mechanism in your browser.