# Why are cookies unavailable from Opera extension background page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies, opera-extension

I try to write Opera extension, it must be able to call AJAX requests to third-party site.

What I have in config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

I am authorized on this third-party site:
[image: please find that cookie exists]

I call AJAX using jQuery from background page in a very simple way:

```
$.ajax(params);
```

What I get in Dragonfly? AJAX call is sent, but no cookies in request. Please see a screenshot:
[image]

Problem exists only on extension background page. Simple access to this site transfers cookies well.

What am I doing wrong? How to make background page see my cookies? Or what is another way to call third-party site from my extension?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-is-jquerys-ajax-method-not-sending-my-session-cookie and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054316/jquery-sending-credentials-with-cross-domain-posts

Comment: Thanks Larry, I am afraid it is not a duplicate. I tried to set withCredentials field. Also I've checked domain - it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

When I read Ajax request to third party site I directly think about cross domain restrictions:
[Cross domain cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084114/cross-domain-cookies)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but cross domain cookies are allowed for browser extensions...

Comment: @DmitryTarasov if you have an article that explains that please post it, I know that they are secured by the browser.