# Setting Session/Cookie Domain on Fly or Setting Multiple Session/Cookie Domains

Tags: php, session, cookies, cross-domain

I'm working on a site that works with subdomains and cnames. For the sites initial load I have set:

```
.example.com
```

This allows cookies and session to work under all subdomains of .example.com .But then the cnames can be change so `www.mysite.com` points to `domain1.example.com` , which breaks all the sesssions and cookies.

So my question is, is it possible to either change phps cookie's domain after is has already been set OR append domain1.example.com to .example.com?

PS. The site must work under both domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cookies can only be set/read by a single domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1095901/2119660).  With two domains (such as mysite.com and example.com) you'll need to set two separate cookies, or use one of the strategies in that StackOverflow post to get around this built-in limitation to cookies.