# Logging into a form, server-side with curl, then carry cookies back to the browser

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I have the following code which is doing an HTTP/POST to log into a web form. The cookies returned by the site are stored in the file `cookies.txt`.

```
$ch = curl_init();

$opts = array(
    CURLOPT_URL=> $projectUrl,
    CURLOPT_POST=> true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=> true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=> true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR=> 'cookies.txt',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=> http_build_query($data),
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);

$ret = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

I've confirmed that the login is successful (because the value of `$ret` is the content of the page behind the form.

Next, I have a little bit of code which parses the cookie file written by curl and does a `set_cookie` for each cookie.

As far as I can tell, this is always just the PHPSESSION cookie.

```
$cookies = parseCookieFile('cookies.txt');
foreach($cookies as $c) {
    if(!setcookie($c["name"], $c["value"], $c["expires"], $c["path"], $c["domain"], $c["secure"])) {
        echo "ERROR: Could not write cookie {$c["name"]}<br />";
    }
}
```

My hope was, having done all this on the backend, I'd be able to browse to the site I logged into and it would detect the session cookies and pass me on through.

Unfortunately, this is not the case. I just end up back at the login form.

Is there some stupid/obvious reason why this isn't going to work?

Comment: You need to use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');`

Comment: My understanding was that CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE was if I wanted successive curl calls to use the same cookies. I want to carry the cookies generated from the server-side code over to the end-user's browser.

Comment: @MarkBiek no! you can not set other site's cookie into user's browser. Its a security issue.

Comment: Oh I understand... You can't set cookies for another domain - that'd be a huge security vuln

Comment: That makes sense. I just wasn't sure since PHP does actually let me write the cookies.

The browser just doesn't appear to recognize them.

One of you should post that as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross domain cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084114/cross-domain-cookies)

Comment: Actually, I found this question which answers things nicely so I'm voting to close mine:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084114/cross-domain-cookies