# How do I send a cookie to a website so I can stay logged in?

Tags: php, curl

I am writing a php script that submits a form with POST method for an external website. I got this to work, however that external website requires me to login. How would I send a cookie to that website to imitate the "Remember me" behavior so I won't need to login?

Comment: Fill up the [cookie jar](http://www.darkbee.be/cookiejar/curl.php) (source at the bottom)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084114/cross-domain-cookies

Comment: (There are better duplicates for cURL+logins+cookies. But since you didn't ask for anything specific; you probably didn't want a specific answer. Else try the search function yourself.)